# Inductive proof and summation: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction

The problem asks me to prove by induction that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

I've worked through it at least half a dozen times, checked my math fastidiously, can't seem to figure it out, so here I am.

For a base case I use 2, gets me 9 for both, inductive step leaves me with:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^3 = \frac{(k+1)^2 * (k+2)^2}{4}$$

Expanding things, I square the binomials to get $(k^2+2k+2)(k^2+4k+4)$
Taking it from there (and I won't go through the steps of multiplying them together and combining like terms) I am left with:
$$\frac{k^4+6k^3+14k^2+16k+8}{4}$$
Plugging in 2 again yields 36 for the summation portion but 40 for the fraction part, trying it with 3 yields equally unequal answers.  If someone could please point me to the spot where I am making my error it would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You've gone wrong on the easy bit: $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$!

---

You can avoid full expansion of the numerator in various ways, for example by computing

$$\frac {(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}4-\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4=\frac {(n+1)^2}4\cdot\left ((n+2)^2-n^2\right)$$

And the final bracket is the difference of two squares and comes to $2(2n+2)=4(n+1)$

Comment: I am genuinely ashamed...I should be kicked out of college for this.  The amount of effort I put into this...and missing that.  Thank you sir....time to go back to 1st grade!

Comment: @user3216655 It is so easy to do - I've done it on this site with the easy bit of an answer, while concentration on getting something else right. The point is to learn from this - to notice what kind of mistake it is, so you are less likely to do something similar again.

Comment: @user3216655 I added a different comment to show how to avoid expanding anything.

Answer (score 2):

The inductive step would require showing that
$$
\left[n^{2}(n+1)^{2}/4\right]+(n+1)^{3}=(n+1)^{2}((n+1)+1)^{2}/4.
$$