# Prove the following claim $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i^{3} = \frac 14(n^4 - 3n^2 + 2n^2 + 4)$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{3} = \frac 14(n^4 - 3n^2 + 2n^2 + 4)$$

This is what I have so far : proof by induction

Base Case : for n = 1
$$1 = \frac 14(1^4-3(1)^3+2(1)^2 + 4)$$
$$1 = 1$$

Base case is true

Induction step: Assume the above is true for n = k and now show it for n = k+1

$$\frac 14(k^4 - 3k^2 + 2k^2 + 4) + (k+1)^3 = \frac 14((k+1)^4 - 3(k+1)^2 + 2(k+1)^2 + 4)$$

$$\frac 14(k^4-3k^3+2k+4) + \frac 44(k^3+3k^2+3k+1) = \frac 14(k^4 + k^3-k^2-3k + 4)$$
$$\frac 14(k^4+k^3+12k^2+14k+8) = \frac 14(k^4 + k^3-k^2-3k + 4)$$

which is obviously not the same thing.  I don't know what am I doing wrong here.  Can this be prove or there is a counter example for it.

Comment: The claim is false. It should be $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3=\frac 14(n^4+2n^3+n^2)$.

Comment: duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/734435)

Comment: An intriguing corollary of $\sum_{i=1}^ni^3=n^2(n+1)^2/4$ is that $(\sum_{i=1}^ni)^2=\sum_{i=1}^ni^3.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got it thanks.  This is false claim because if we let n =2 we can give a counter example

$$2^3 = (2^4-3(2)^3+2(2)^2 + 4)/4$$
$$8 = (16-24+8 + 4)/4$$
$$8 != 1 $$

Hense its false